# moving from procedural code to oop

Tags: php, ajax, json, oop

Im relatively  new to programming, with about 1 years part-time learning experience, im very new to PHP, only about a few weeks and using w3schools to help me

Im now trying to make the switch to OOP style and just cant understand the concept, or rather how and when to apply it and have thus turned here, where I have been a long time lurker instead of contributor for some help and advice.

I would like some help / short explanation how I would write the folloing in a PHP oop way

```
$sql="SELECT name, lastname, member_nr, joindate, order, creditCardInfo
 from members 
 WHERE member_nr = $'member_nr'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("error");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array){
  echo '<h3>Personal Profile</h3>';
 echo  $name = $row['name'];
  echo $lastName = $row['lastname'];
 :
 :
 }
```

My problem is I dont know if I should create a class for the above, personal profile can be seen as a person right which is an object...? But do I include the HTML part and the mysql_query part etc in my class...Ive just got so many questions when it comes to OOP, its very hard to learn on your own thats why im really appreciate any drop of help or advice I can get on here

Thank you

Comment: don't jump into writing full-blowin OOP. start with OOB - object-oriented BASED.e .g. use objects, just don't start defining your own.

Comment: Try to think about what actions your code performs...in this case it 1. accesses the DB 2. Formats the data from the DB and 3. Outputs HTML.

Comment: @STLMikey thank you that a nice tip, but where to from there do I now need to create 3 different functions for the 3 different actions...its on points like these that im stuck

Answer (score 2):

First you should use `mysqli`, as all `mysql_*` are deprecated and are removed from PHP in the future.

Here a basis class with some functions, but you should expand it for your use! And learn what the functions do which got no comments on your own, to learn more.
This makes multiple connections to the database, so reading some stuff about singleton would be good for you too!

```
<?php
class dbconnection {
    private $dbHostname;
    private $dbName;
    private $dbUsername;
    private $dbUserpassword;

    private $error;
    private $querysuccess;
    private $connected;

    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dbHostname = 'localhost';
        $this->dbName = 'databasename';
        $this->dbUsername = 'username';
        $this->dbUserpassword = 'password';
        $this->connected = false;
    }
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->mysqli->Close();
    }

    public function connect() {
        //establishing a database connection
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->dbHostname, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbUserpassword, $this->dbName);
        if($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {//When there was an error during the connecting
            echo 'Connection Error:<br>'.$this->mysqli->connect_error;
            $this->connected = false;
        } else {
            $this->connected = true;
        }
        if(!$this->mysqli->set_charset('utf8')) {//Need to be done for some functions!
            echo 'Error during seting the charset: <br>'.$this->mysqli->error;
        }
    }

    public function doquery($query_str) {
        //method which executes the query
        $returnval = false;
        if($this->connected && $query_str != '') {
            //only when connected AND the query is not empty
            $res = $this->mysqli->query($query_str);//this is the equivalent of mysql_query
            if($this->error_get() == '') {//Check for an error
                $this->querysuccess = true;
            } else {
                $this->querysuccess = false;
            }
            $returnval = $res;
        } else {
            echo 'No database connection, this needs some!';
        }
        return $returnval;
    }
    public function query_success() {
        return $this->querysuccess;
    }
    public function affected_rows_get() {
        return $this->mysqli->affected_rows;
    }
    public function error_get() {
        return $this->mysqli->error;
    }
    public function insert_id_get() {
        return $this->mysqli->insert_id;
    }
    public function escape_str($str) {
        return $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($str);
    }
    public function is_connected() {
        return $this->connected;
    }
    public function fetch_assoc(&$res){
        return $res->fetch_assoc();
    }
    public function fetch_assoc_array(&$res){
        return $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This case wouldn't be a good example.  You want a class when you want to encapsulate logic of one entity to simplify its use outside the class.

For example:

```
class Member {
   private $id, $name, 
           $lastname, $member_nr, $joindate, $order, $creditCardInfo;
   public function __construct($id = 0) {
        if($id != null) $this->loadFromDB();
   }

   private function loadFromDB() {
       //Do db load here...
   }

   public function Update(){
      //Do db update
   }

   public function Delete() {
      //Do db delete...
   }

   public function GetFromMemberNR($nr) {
        //Do select
   }

   //Additional Functions Verfication
}
```

In the end you'll have fairly complex code here. But to use it outside you just include the class's php file.

```
include 'member.php';
$member = new Member();
$member->GetFromMemberNR(2); //Does everything for you inside the function..
```

There are plenty of tools to help you do database operations easier, but that is the basis of OOP.  The main idea is Encapsulation for reusability.

Comment: thank you I can clearly see the benefit in OOP from your example, its just so difficult to grasp...

Comment: its like you are learning a new language all together from scratch

Comment: Its good to do though.  A lot of languages benefit from this programming style.  Code reuse is the main benefit.  You just call it once and you can use it everywhere.  Combine it with tools like Composer which helps you with autoloading classes and you have a powerful dynamic library of code without having to worry so much about remembering where you put that one bit of code.